# Translating Python (requests) API call to R (httr)

Tags: python, r, json, python-requests, httr

As the title suggest, I am having a hard time querying an API with httr in R, which works well in Python using requests. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and don't have much experience with these type of requests. I've been searching around, but can't seem to find the answer, any help would be appreciated. API endpoint documentation: https://docs.scifeon.com/developer/reference/http-api/endpoints/query

Works in python:

```
import requests

username = "myemail@web.com"
personal_access_token = "mytoken"
url = "https://provider/api/query/dataset"

header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
query = [
{
    "eClass": "Fermentation", 
    "collection": "fermentations", 
    "filters": [{ "field": "attributes.experiment", "value": "expnumber"},], 
}
]

response = requests.request("POST", 
                    url, 
                    headers=header, 
                    json=query, 
                    auth=(
                        username, 
                        personal_access_token
                        )
                    )

response.json()
```

This python snippet gives the expected json output.
However, this does not work in R:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

username = "myemail@web.com"
personal_access_token = "mytoken"
url = "https://provider/api/query/dataset"

query <- list(eClass = "Fermentation",
            collection = "fermentations",
            filters = list(field = "attributes.experiment", value = "expnumber"))

response <- POST(url,
     add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"),
     authenticate(username, personal_access_token),
     body = query, 
     encode = 'json'
     )

content(response)
```

The R response is:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$code
[1] 1

[[1]]$message
[1] "Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'."

[[1]]$hint
[1] ""

[[1]]$exception
[[1]]$exception$message
[1] "Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'."

[[1]]$exception$stackTrace
[1] ""

[[1]]$exception$innerException
NULL


[[1]]$stacktrace
[1] ""
```

Comment: Try `filters = list(list(field = "attributes.experiment", value = "expnumber"))`. It's very difficult to help without some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that we can use for testing or documentation for the particular API endpoint in question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your suggestion unfortunatly didn't work, and I cannot give a reproducible example due to the confidentiality of the data. However, here is a link to the documentation for the API endpoint: https://docs.scifeon.com/developer/reference/http-api/endpoints/query

Comment: Any help on this issue would be appreciated. I've played around a bit with the python and R script, and it seems that the issue is the format for the query in R. I just don't know how it should be formatted differently, to give a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation more closely, I found that the query just needed to be in JSON format. The following works in R now:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

username = "myemail@web.com"
personal_access_token = "mytoken"
url = "https://provider/api/query/dataset"

query_json <- data.frame(eClass = "Fermentation", 
                         collection = "fermentations")
filters <- data.frame(field = "attributes.experiment", 
                      value = "expnumber")
query_json[1, "filters"][[1]] <- list(filters)
query_json <- toJSON(query_json)

response <- POST(url,
                 add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"),
                 authenticate(username, personal_access_token),
                 body = query_json, 
                 encode = 'json'
)

content(response)
```